# build jdee with emacs on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

I am a new Ubuntu user running 13.04. I want to install Emacs 24 with jdee. I successfully installed Emacs 24 through apt-get, but am uncertain how to install jdee. I have a zip file called jdee-bin-2.4.1.zip but am not sure what to do next. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First, extract the zip to your emacs folder:

```
$ cd ~/.emacs.d
$ tar jxf ~/Downloads/jdee-bin-2.4.1.bz2
```

Second, Open EMacs and import jdee:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/jdee-2.4.1/lisp")
(load "jde")
```

[From the Manual](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/install.html#install-binary)

Comment: Will this add jdee to emacs permanently or does it need done each time emacs is opened?

Comment: From the same page "You should add these two lines to your Emacs initialization file (with the path to the JDEE directory adjusted to your chosen installation location) so JDEE is available each time you start Emacs. The initialization file is typically ~/.emacs.d/init.el (or ~/.emacs)."